# Reinforcement learning for advertising campaigns

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am new to reinforcement learning and am trying to understand whether the following is suitable for reinforcement learning and if so, how I should approach the problem.

I work for a company that creates advertising campaigns for online retailers. Specifically, we group their products into campaigns based on past performance and then for each campaign set a budget and a target return on advertising spend (roas). These campaigns are then passed to google.

Here is my attempt at framing this as a reinforcement learning problem:

- The goal is to maximise roas whilst also spending the budget.
- The current state of an account can be described by a 3 x 3 grid, showing whether over the past N days, the account is spending below / above or at its target and whether it is below / above or at its roas target. If an account is below its roas and below its spend, that is the worst possible state given the goal.
- The action that the agent could take would be to change the budget and/or change the target roas. These would be account level targets that then feed down to the campaigns when they are created.
- I am unclear how to define the rewards, but my best guess would be to have the reward be based on the state that the account is in at the next time step.

Questions:

- How can I get started with this problem? Can you point me towards any useful resources?
- Whilst we have historical data for the state that the account was in, we have not taken these actions in the past. Is this an environment that could be simulated in order to train a model? How?
- We have lots of customers operating in different markets who's performance will be affected by different external factors. How does this influence the approach to the problem?
- What reinforcement learning algorithm would be best suited? or do I need to try multiple?